# How to give symbols in R a certain colour?

Tags: r

I have 3 different groups in a PCA plot and assigned a symbol to each group.

```
data_pca$symbol[which(data_pca$Species == "species 1")] <- 15
data_pca$symbol[which(data_pca$Species == "species 2")] <- 17
data_pca$symbol[which(data_pca$Species == "species 3")] <- 18
```

Now I would like to colour these symbols in a specific colour but if I use

```
plot(data_pca$Comp1, data_pca$Comp2, pch=data_pca$symbol, cex=1.5, col=data_pca$symbol)
```

then R chooses the colours.

How can I define the colours for the group symbols?

Comment: Specify a vector of named colors, or a palette: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just assign colours manually, like you did with the symbols. You can simplify this, however …

```
colors = c(`Species 1` = 'red', `Species 2` = 'green', `Species 3` = 'goldenrod')

plot(…, col = colors[data_pca$Species])
```

The same simplification can (should?) be done for the point character (symbol type) as well.

Comment: `colors` is actually a defined function in `grDevices` that returns color names known to R. see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/colors.html

Comment: @Gary I know, but so what? It’s a fitting variable name here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph only in case the OP wanted to use `colors <- colors(3)` or something similar, for clarity...

Comment: @Gary That actually still works in R … functions and variables are looked up separately (cf. [`match.fun`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.fun.html)) so having a variable named the same as a function, and using both, makes sense in (some!) contexts, and with a generally-named function such as `colors`, that’s a case where I recommend it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, definitely works in R, which is cool and dangerous, although not in this case. As I said, my point was just about clarity. A coding style choice, not dealbreaker...

Answer (score 0):

I like to control colors from the original data:

```
data_pca$mycolor <- 'red' # the default
data_pca$mycolor[data_pca$symbol==17] <-'blue'
data_pca$mycolor[data_pca$symbol==18] <- 'green'

plot(...,col=data_pca$mycolor)
```